# Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una duda, estoy creando una base de datos y quiero que se muestre la información de la tabla en mi pagina html. Pero me aparece eso. Agradecería su ayuda. Este es mi código:
Aplicando las modificaciones que me mencionan quedaría así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Raptors Food</title>
</head>
<body>
   <?php
      require 'database.php';
      $consulta= "SELECT * FROM comida";
      $resultado= mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
      echo "<table>";
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<th>"."idcomida"."</th>";
      echo "<th>"."nombre"."</th>";
      echo "<th>"."descripcion"."</th>";
      echo "<th>"."costo"."</th>";
      echo "<th>"."cantidad"."</th>";
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            echo $idcomida = $row['id_comida'];
            echo $nombre = $row['nombre'];
            echo $descripcion = $row['descripcion'];
            echo $costo = $row['precio'];
            echo $cant_disponible = $row['cant_disponible'];
      }
      echo "</table>";
   ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Me aparecen errores

> Notice: Undefined variable: resultado in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-login\consultas.php on line 17
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-login\consultas.php on line 17

Comment: ¿cuál es la finalidad de esta línea? `$inc = require'database.php';`

Comment: Llamar el código que solamente hace conexión con la BD

Comment: una vez que haces tu consulta, la intención es imprimir el último valor obtenido o todos los registros de la tabla a la cual consultas?

Comment: Si, realmente esa es la intención

Comment: veo que estás haciendo un `require` de `database.php` en la vista donde imprimes los datos, ahí guardaste la consulta? o la consulta la tienes en otro archivo?

Comment: No, database.php es solo la conexión a la base de datos:/

Comment: entonces en la vista debes hacer el `require` pero del archivo donde esta la consulta a la tabla, por que por eso te dice `NULL` por que `$resultado` esta llegando sin valor alguno

Comment: Se nota que soy nueva en esto, la verdad todo lo he sacado a vista de tutoriales. Es un proyecto que estoy sacando por mi cuenta ya que realmente en la escuela no vemos nada de esto, pero quiero experimentarlo. Perdón por causar molestias, pero es que realmente no entiendo cuál es el problema, realmente me marca error inicialmente en la línea de mysqli_query

Comment: No causas molestías, solo realiza el cambio que te digo, deja edito mi respuesta haber si te sirve

Comment: Gracias :’) y bueno, si, ya tengo los tres archivos, uno que hace la conexión a la BD, el que hace la consulta y el último de la vista. Ahora me marca error en la línea cuatro de mi archivo de consulta.php, exactamente en el mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta); y en el archivo de vista exactamente en el while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC))

Comment: Las líneas de código de consulta.php son;

Comment: require ‘database.php’;

Comment: $consulta= ‘SELECT *FROM comida’;    Y por ultimo la línea $resultado=mysqli__query($conexion,$consulta)

Comment: Tienes seguridad de que la variable `$conexion` ya esta declarada en el archivo que estas incluyendo?

Comment: Ya solucione el problema. Realmente mi error estaba en el archivo database.php, (en el cual prácticamente combinaba un objeto PDO con mysqli, entonces al momento que hacia mi consulta, mysqli no tenía  referencias a la base. Entonces como no conozco tanto OOP en PHP, preferí ocupar mysqli en su totalidad.